# Pandas str.replace using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am hoping to clear out some titles from a names column I have and trying to do it via a dictionary.

```
d = {' DR ':'',' Father ':'',' FR ':'',' M ':'',' ME ':'',' MISS ':'',' MR ':'',' Mr ':'',' MRS ':'',' Mrs ':'',' MS ':'',' Ms ':'',' Mstr ':'',' Professor ':'',' SR ':''}

print(df):

NAME

James MR 
John Fr 
Natasha Ms
Judy MRS
```

I am using the line `df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].replace(d)` but nothing is happening.

Anything i need to add? IHave tried variations of `.str.replace` but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us add `regex`

```
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].replace(d,regex=True)
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much @YOBEN_S...i know it had to be something simple but couldnt find it in the documentation